# Two Flash questions

Tags: flash

1. What does _level0,_parent and _root mean in flash?
2. What's the difference between absolute path and relative path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Levels in Flash are the base root element of everything.

Every `level` has an associated `_root` element, which is the base of all attached movieclips, whether on stages or dynamically loaded.

`_parent` is the previous element along the element hierarchy. For example, if `_root` has movie clip `n` loaded into it, then the `n._parent == _root`.

Absolute path and relative paths mean the exact same thing as in any OS. The relative path is relative to your initial container clip. Absolute path is absolute to your OS.